# Dreamweaver Regex Help

Tags: php, regex

Hi i am trying to do a find and replace on files for this

`<?php include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/articles/[^a-z]/footer.php"; ?>`

to

`<?php include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/includes/class/footer.php"; ?>`

but for some reason it is not working! i have a clue that its the / messing it up?

Cheers

Comment: Impossible to tell. You realize that `[^a-z]` matches one single character other than the ascii range `a-z`, right? What strings are you trying to replace?

Comment: i need to just mask the a-z part as its always differnt like
english,russian,french ect ect

Answer (score 1):

If you are using regex's, you will need to escape all the special chars...

```
<\?php include \$_SERVER\["DOCUMENT_ROOT"\]\."/articles/[^a-z]+/footer\.php"; \?>
```

to

```
<?php include \$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/includes/class/footer.php"; ?>
```

**NOTE**: I changed the a-z to match multiple characters. If you only want a single non a-z character, take out the +

Comment: i tryed this example with reg enabled and it failes to find anything, hmmm

Answer (score 0):

You know that [^a-z] means search for anything but chars from a-z?

Try it with [a-z]+  instead. :)